# Why does git gives different diff results with different text attribute?

Tags: git

I found that when I change the text attribute in .gitattributes, git gives me a different diff result. Can anyone explain to me please?

Here is what I did:

1. Add a .gitattributes file with content `* -text`
2. Add another text file with some content
3. Commit

Then I added a line "ddd" and `git diff`, the result is as expected

```
diff --git a/abc.txt b/abc.txt
index aa3b7ba..911ddef 100644
--- a/abc.txt
+++ b/abc.txt
@@ -2,3 +2,5 @@ aaa
 bbb
 ccc
+ddd^M
+
```

But when I changed .gitattributes to `* text` and diff again, git gave me this:

```
diff --git a/abc.txt b/abc.txt
index aa3b7ba..9a3ed4f 100644
--- a/abc.txt
+++ b/abc.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
-aaa
-bbb
-ccc
+aaa
+bbb
+ccc
+ddd
+
```

As far as I know, the text attribute is only for eol normalization. Why does it affect the diff result?

Comment: You seem to be saving the file with MSWin line ends, but the original has *nix line ends. Notice the `^M` in the first diff.

Comment: EOL normalization is performed upon commit. `-text` set option to false. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @choroba no, the original also use crlf. If I changed all the lf to crlf, git will tell me I changed every lines in files.

Comment: @ilmirons I knew that, but it seems nothing to do with my question.

Comment: as I get it it has all to do with question because diff is done against committed version so you have a kind of EOL on file a different kind when it is committed with text option or no change when the option is disabled (-text). Hence the difference.

Comment: @ilmirons I think I know what you mean, but then I got another question. From my understanding, for a txt file, (text=auto) should be equivalent to (text), so setting the attribute to (text=auto) should give me the same result as (text). But setting (text=auto) actually produce the same result as (-text). Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

This all gets a little bit complicated, because there are many moving parts here.  First, let's just talk about `git diff` and "trees".  Then let's look at what kinds of end-of-line modification Git can do, and *when* Git does it.  Then, let's look specifically at what `* -text` and `* text` mean in `.gitattributes`.  Finally, let's consider all of this together with `git diff`.

#### The `git diff` command compares two "trees"

By default—there are specific modes for comparing files, but we're not going to get into those here—running `git diff` compares two of what Git calls *trees*.  A tree is a collection of files, where each file has a name: `a.txt`, `abc.txt`, `dir/c.txt`, `dir/sub/d.txt`, and so on (but we'll stop here for this example).  The top level of this tree is the directory/folder (use whichever term you like) containing `a.txt`, `abc.txt`, and a *sub*-directory/folder `dir`, which Git calls a *sub-tree*.  The sub-tree named `dir` contains `c.txt` and another sub-tree `sub`, and the final sub-tree contains `d.txt`.

Git wants *two* of these trees, though.  One is often a commit, and the other is often also a second (presumably different) commit.  This kind of `git diff` compares the contents of the two commits' trees.

By default, though, `git diff` starts with your *index* as the first tree.  Your index, which Git calls *the* index, or sometimes the *staging-area* or the *cache*, is a special entity that Git mainly uses to build the *next commit you will make*.  The index has a bunch of sub-tasks as well, which is why it has these three different names.  (We're going to see one of the extra tasks near the end of this answer.)  The index starts out with a copy of everything in the *current* commit: the commit you have run `git checkout` on.  So, initially at least, the index matches the current commit.

You also have a *work-tree*.  The work-tree is pretty simple: it's where you do your work.  Git needs you to have a work-tree because all the files that Git stores, in a commit or in the index, are in a special, highly-compressed, Git-only format.  (Technically, these are Git *blob objects*.)  Most programs on your computer, including your own text editors and compilers and so on, can't deal with Git-only files.  These programs need files to have the normal every day file format, so Git extracts the Git-only files into normal format in your work-tree.

Every time you `git add` a file like `abc.txt`, Git copies that file from your work-tree into the special Git-only format and stuffs the special blob hash ID into the index.  So if you *change* a file in your work-tree, then `git add` the changed file, Git copies the changes into the repository (as a blob object) and puts the new hash ID into the index, replacing the previous index version with the copied-from-work-tree version.  Note that the index *continuously* has *some* version of `abc.txt`.  At first, it has the current commit's version.  Then, after `git add abc.txt`, it has the work-tree's version (though in special Git-only format now).

Anyway, that's most of what we need to know about the index here: that it contains, as a variant of a Git "tree", everything that will go into the *next* commit.  Initially, that's the same as everything in the commit we just checked out.

We've already mentioned the work-tree, and that it's in a normal, not-so-good-for-Git form.  Nonetheless, various Git commands can work with it as a tree as well, and `git diff` is one of those.  Git will treat each directory/folder as a sub-tree, with the work-tree itself being the top level tree.  Each file in the tree acts like a Git blob object, but each file is in its own, normal-on-the-computer form, rather than in the special Git-only form.

So: running `git diff` with no arguments compares the *index* to the *work-tree*.  In both cases, Git uses them as if they were Git's internal "tree" objects.  It's important to remember just what it is Git is comparing, though: right now it's index vs work-tree.  This becomes even more important in a moment.

#### End-of-line modifications

Git's special, internal, Git-only format is designed to be good for Git.  It was also designed by Linus Torvalds, so as you might expect, it's very Linux-friendly.  As a result, you could say that it would rather have text files have lines that end with a plain newline `\n` character, rather than a DOS/Windows-style CRLF (or `\r\n`) sequence.  This is a bit of an overstatement:  Git really *doesn't care at all* about this.  But a lot of people *using* Git *do* care, and for whatever reasons, whether you like them or not, `\n`-only is the normal Git internal format at this point, for text files.  You don't *have* to use this, but many people do use this.

Meanwhile, your work-tree, being on your computer using your computer's preferred ("normal") format, may well have text files that have CR-LF (which I'll spell without the hyphen from here on out) line endings, if you use DOS/Windows.  So the Git folks have kindly provided some translation software, built into Git.  It will, when working on text files, either turn CRLF line endings into `\n`-only endings, or turn `\n`-only endings into CRLF endings.  To do this, Git needs to know *which files are text*.  We'll come back to this in a moment.  It also needs to have some *particular points of translation:*  If Git is going to replace a `\n` with CRLF, *when* will it do this?  If Git is going to replace a CRLF pair with `\n`, *when* will it do this?

The other important question here is: *What is the "normal" or "preferred" format on this computer?*  This is where `core.eol` comes in: on Windows, `core.eol` is normally set to CRLF, and on Linux, `core.eol` defaults to just a newline `\n`.  That's the "normal" setting for that computer.  More precisely, `core.eol` defaults to `native`, and `native` *means* CRLF on DOS/Windows, but `\n` on Linux/Unix.

#### The index <-> work-tree is "when"

Note that in all the index manipulation above, there are *three* versions of every file at all times:

```
current commit       index       work-tree
--------------      -------      ---------
       a.txt          a.txt         a.txt
     abc.txt        abc.txt       abc.txt
```

The first two columns, "current commit" and "index", are in the internal, Git-only format.  Moreover, no commit can *ever* be changed (this is a fundamental Git property: no object can ever change), so the version saved forever in the current commit is read-only.  The work-tree version is in your normal format.  So it makes sense that the internal, commit form would be `\n`-only, and the work-tree form would be CRLF.

Meanwhile, the internal index file is in the special Git-only format too.  So it should, logically, have the `\n`-only form, and it does.  And, Git can copy from the work-tree to the index (`git add`), or copy from the index to the work-tree (`git checkout` and `git reset`), so this is the obvious place to put the `\n`-to-CRLF and CRLF-to-`\n` conversion.

And that's where it is: Git does `\n`-to-CRLF when copying from the index to the work-tree.  Git does CRLF-to-`\n` when copying from the work-tree to the index.

Well, that's where *most of it* is, and there is another twist as well, as we will see in a bit.

#### What `.gitattributes` does

Each `.gitattributes` entry gives you a way to control the transformations that Git is going to apply.  We mentioned above that Git needs to do this CR-LF stuff on *text* files.  But which files are text files?  The file `abc.txt` is probably a text file.  But what about `README`?  What if it's named `README.md`?  What if `.md` doesn't mean "markdown" but rather means "magic database" which is a binary file?

Git's default on DOS/Windows is to *guess*, based on the file contents, whether a file is text or binary.  This works well enough for some cases.  You can tell it, though: `*.txt text` says that all files named `*.txt` *are* text files, while `*.jpg -text` says that all files named `*.jpg` are *not* text files (are binary files).

A text file gets end-of-line conversions applied.  You can choose which end-of-line conversions Git should do, on a per-file-name basis, in `.gitattributes` as well, but a simple `text` means *this file is text, not binary, so do the normal conversions, whatever those are.*  Again, they depend on `core.eol`, which defaults to `native`, which defaults to CRLF on DOS/Windows.

#### Now we have the hard/tricky part

Git normally does all the CRLF conversions on `git add` (copy from work-tree to index: convert from native to Git internal) and `git checkout` (copy from index to work-tree: convert from Git internal to native).  But if `git diff` is going to compare the index to the work-tree, we have a problem: the index is in Git-internal format, and the work-tree is in native format.  How can we diff these?

Git's answer is that it will, at least temporarily, *convert the work-tree files to the internal format for the purpose of diffing them.*  Either direction would suffice in theory, but this is the direction the Git programmers chose.  So there's one extra point where Git does this conversion, and that's when you run `git diff`.

Or is it?  Well, the answer is both no and yes.  It's complicated!

#### The index is also a cache

On my (Linux/Unix) system, I made a Git repository and created a file, `foo.txt`, with two lines that, on purpose, both end with CRLF endings:

```
$ vis foo.txt
this file has\^M
crlf line endings\^M
```

(the `vis` program displays CRLF endings this way, and omits the `\^M` when the file doesn't end with CRLF).

I committed this file, in this form, as a binary file so that it went this way into Git (this is easier on Unix-ish systems, where "no `.gitattributes` means files are all just unmodified by Git").

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I created a `.gitattributes` to force Git to treat the file as text:

```
$ echo '* text' > .gitattributes
```

Curiously, nothing happens yet:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitattributes

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Now I use the `touch` command to change the *time stamp* on the file, without changing its contents, and run `git status` again:

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   foo.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitattributes

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What happened?  The `touch` command didn't change the file, but it *did* change the *time stamp* on the file.  And, `git status` runs `git diff`, and *now* `git diff` "sees" the file as different from the index version, even though both files are the same.

The reason is that Git uses the index as both *a place to keep the cleaned, Git-ized file **and** a way to know if the cleaned, Git-ized file matches the work-tree file.*  It's the time stamps that tell Git the latter.  By `touch`ing the file, I changed the time stamps, so that Git no longer believes that the index file matches the work-tree file.  Now Git realizes that it must Git-ize the work-tree version of `foo.txt`, so when it does that, we see a difference (though we need `vis` to see it):

```
$ git diff | vis
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in foo.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 257cbae..6bf00d0 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-this file has\^M
-crlf line endings\^M
+this file has
+crlf line endings
```

If I were to run `git add foo.txt` right now, Git would "clean" the CRLFs, replacing them with `\n` endings.  The `git diff` of the current index version and the cleaned work-tree version shows a change to remove the carriage returns (`\r`, or `\^M` as `vis` shows them here).

If I remove the `.gitattributes` file now, or change it to `* -text`, the status changes and the `git diff` output disappears:

```
$ echo '* -text' > .gitattributes
$ git diff
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitattributes

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

This is because the file will no longer have CRLF replaced with LF-only, so now the file in the work-tree really *does* match the file in the index, even after "cleaning" (which changes no data).

#### Note some special conditions

In order to get into this situation, I had to create a file and commit it, with the file having CRLF endings in it in both the work-tree form and the internal, Git-ized form.  That's easier on a Linux/Unix system since the Git default here is: *don't mess with any of my data, ever.*  That was actually Linus' original desire for Git; all the CRLF stuff was added later, for those who need to use Windows.

The `* text` attribute in `.gitattributes` not only tells Git that the file is definitely text (i.e., do mess with it during copies in and out of the index), but also that the file is definitely text for `git diff` purposes.  A line reading `* -text` tells Git that the file is definitely *not* text: don't mess with its data during copies in and out of the index.

There are some separate controls to tell Git that `git diff` shouldn't even *attempt* to diff the file, by default, because it's not text.  The default is to do the same kind of "is it text" auto-detection that Git will do if you don't explicitly label a file, and are on DOS/Windows.  Besides that there is a setting, `core.bigFileThreshold`, that makes Git skip the diff.  Since your file really is text, and isn't too big, you got `git diff` output.  It looks like all the lines changed, and they probably traded CRLF endings for plain-newline endings or vice versa.  The peculiar thing is the one `^M` shown.  That's probably from a line that has CR CR LF as its last three bytes,<sup>1</sup> but exactly how you got that is a mystery.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `less` pager knows to display CR-LF endings without displaying a control-M, but will display `^M` at the end of a line that ends with two `^M`s, i.e., with CR-CR-LF.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.But I found that changing gitattributes to(* text=auto) produce an unexpected result according to your explaination.  From my understanding, for a txt file, (text=auto) should be equivalent to (text), so the file should be normalized and diff should give a "all lines changed" result. But it actually produce the same result as (-text). Why is it so?

Comment: `text=auto` would indeed be the same as `text` if the auto-detection detects text. Beware of the cache aspect of the index, though: you may need to modify the file timestamps on the work-tree in order to see any effect. Note that `git status` and other operations update the cached time stamp.